# How do I make a query search in rails case insensitive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, search

I have this search method in my user.rb model

```
def self.search(query)
    where("description like ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

but my search is case sensitive. I want to make it case insensitive. How do I do that? I'm hoping it's a quick fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using postgresql:

```
def self.search(query)
  where("description ilike ?", "%#{query}%")
end
```

Just use `ilike` instead of `like`. [like/ilike documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE)

If you want to use =, both sides either UPPER or LOWER

Comment: Keep in mind that standard indexes will not be utilized when using ILIKE.